# How to Display Parent-Child Relationship in a single datagrid Windows Forms .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, parent-child

I need to know is there a way to dispaly parent-child relation in a single datagrid in Windows Forms .Net C#

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of googling I came up with a post on the msdn forums where they where looking for the same functionality.

Basically what you can do is host a datagridview inside a templatecolumn of your datagrid.

you can find this post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0a63a483-5b15-40d6-afb4-8add6b4f244f

Answer (score 0):

Not in a single datagrid - you need to use a nested repeater / datalist / listview in order to bind the child rows when the parent row is bound.